# Favicon won't show, seems to be issue with webpack

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, webpack, favicon

I've got a React/Redux app and I'm using webpack to transpile my JSX and ES6 and load my stylesheets and images into my JS. My dev server is hosted on port 3000.

Here's my webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './src/js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      favicon: 'src/images/favicon.ico'
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loaders: [ 'babel' ],
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      include: __dirname
    }, {
      test: /\.less?$/,
      loaders: [ 'style', 'css', 'less' ],
      include: __dirname
    },
    {
      test: /\.(otf|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
      loaders: [ 'url' ],
      include: __dirname
    },
    {
      test: /\.(png|ico|gif)?$/,
      loaders: [ 'file' ],
      include: __dirname
    }]
  }
};
```

When I hit localhost:3000, everything that I would expect to be there is there, except my favicon. If I go to localhost:3000/static/favicon.ico, my favicon is there. Could use some expertise debugging this issue.

Comment: What do you see at `localhost:3000/favicon.ico`?  That's where the browser looks for it...

Comment: 404, but I also point to /static/favicon.ico in my index.html.

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/favicon.ico" "image/x-icon" />`

Comment: I now see it at localhost:3000/favicon.ico by using the 'serve-favicon' middleware for my express web server, but still no luck even after clearing my cache and changing my link tag in index.html to `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />`

Comment: Interesting... is this all browsers?  Perhaps drop the leading `/` to make it a relative path?  To quote [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types): "The shortcut link type is often seen before icon, but this link type is non-conforming, ignored and web authors must not use it anymore." - perhaps try the standards-compliant `<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" />`, or remove it altogether as that represents default behaviour anyway.

Comment: I tried dropping the leading `/` and using `icon` instead of `shortcut icon`, and neither works. I forgot to mention I do see my favicon when I open the browser directly from my html, just not when I hit my webserver (when I've compiled all my js)

Comment: What webserver are you using, and how are you serving static assets?

Comment: I'm using a node server and express's middleware to serve it up. Nothing like Nginx/Apache, and I've never had this issue before with node

Comment: Are you using `express.static()`?

Comment: using `serve-favicon`

Comment: I have exactly same issue with `webpack-dev-server` ;(

Comment: I'm seeing this inconsistently as well...

Answer (score 3):

The browser will look for your favicon in `localhost:3000/favicon.ico`, so that's where it needs to be. Try rewriting the url to serve `favicon.ico` for the `/favicon.ico` route. For example, if you're using historyApiFallback, do:

```
historyApiFallback: {
    rewrites: [
        // shows favicon
        { from: /favicon.ico/, to: '[path/to/favicon]' }
    ]
}
```